# change magento price when changing custom options

Tags: magento

example http://s22.postimg.org/68tnc5b01/Untitled.jpg

I need to do that when the user selects the product size, the price is changed automatically. How can this be done?

Comment: You need to bribe your question.

Comment: You need to show us the code that you have already tried to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through configurable products.

Step 1- Create different products for each size and color.

Step 2- Create one configurable product, and associate the above created products into it.

Here is tutoral how to create configurable product.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product